# Difference between 2 vs "\2"

Tags: c, security, ipsec

While trying to implement the IKE session key generation algorithms I came across the following code snippets for the following algorithm implementation
Algorithm for generating a certain session key

`SKEYID_e = HMAC (SKEYID, SKEYID_a || gxy || CKY-I || CKY-R || 2)`

implementation to get the last concatenation HMAC of digit 2

`hmac_update(ctx, (unsigned char *) "\2", 1)`

here hmac_update is the API used to concatenate the buffer to get the HMAC before finalizing the digest and CTX is HMAC context "\2" is adding the digit 2 and 1 is size of the buffer.

My question is what is the difference between and escaped `unsigned char *` `"\2"` and a `char`/`uint8_t` value `2`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The difference is that a `char` with numeric value 2 and the string `"\2"` is that the former is a `char` and the second is a literal representing a character array containing a `char` with numeric value 2 and then a `char` with numeric value 0. In other words:

- `(char)2` is a single character. Its type is `char`. Its value is 2.
- `"\2"` is an array of characters. Its type decays to `const char*`. Its first entry is 2 and its second entry is 0.

Since `hmac_update` expects as its second argument a pointer to the bytes to use in the update, you can't provide `2` or `(char)2` as an argument, since doing so would try to convert an integer to a pointer (oops). Using `"\2"` solves this problem by providing a pointer to the byte in question. You could also do something like this:

```
const char value = 2;
hmac_update(ctx, &value, 1);
```

Answer (score -1):

"2" describes the character with the hex code 2 (which is a non-printable character, check http://ascii-table.com/info.php?u=x0002);
The digit "2" has the hex code 0x050 = 50, as is the printable character '2'.

Comment: I don't believe this answers the OP's question - they're asking about the difference between "a `char` with numeric value 2` and `"\2"`, not about the difference between "the character `'2'`" and "the character `'\2'`."